# Is it possible to get data from my listview onclick

Tags: android, listview

Hi I have been working through several different tutorials on getting data from a sql database into a listview. I can add data, get data from database and populate the list view, and have a working onclick listener (will fire off a Toast message). However I can not get any data from the listview when clicked. I have tried different combinations of getitem and getItemAtPosition but they all return a empty string(blank toast). Would someone be kind enough to look at my code and tell me if what I am trying to do is possible. In my listview i have four items in each entry, I would like to either get the fourth item directly or get all the items (as string?) then I can pull out the data I need.
Thanks in advance for your time.

```
public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

SQLiteHelper SQLITEHELPER;
SQLiteDatabase SQLITEDATABASE;
Cursor cursor;
SQLiteListAdapter ListAdapter ;

ArrayList<String> ID_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> GENRE_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> NAME_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> URL_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView LISTVIEW;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    LISTVIEW = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    SQLITEHELPER = new SQLiteHelper(this);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    ShowSQLiteDBdata() ;

    super.onResume();
}

private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {

    SQLITEDATABASE = SQLITEHELPER.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = SQLITEDATABASE.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM demoTable1", null);

    ID_ArrayList.clear();
    GENRE_ArrayList.clear();
    NAME_ArrayList.clear();
    URL_ArrayList.clear();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ID_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.KEY_ID)));

           GENRE_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.KEY_Genre)));

            NAME_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.KEY_Name)));

            URL_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.KEY_Url)));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    ListAdapter = new SQLiteListAdapter(ListViewActivity.this,

            ID_ArrayList,
            GENRE_ArrayList,
            NAME_ArrayList,
            URL_ArrayList

    );

    LISTVIEW.setAdapter(ListAdapter);


    LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                                         long id) {
           // String text = (String) LISTVIEW.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            String text = (String) LISTVIEW.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //String text = (String) lv.getItemAtPosition(0);

           // Object item = (Object) LISTVIEW.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    cursor.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LISTVIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        String value1 = ID_ArrayList.get(position);

        String value2 = GENRE_ArrayList.get(position);

        String value3 = NAME_ArrayList.get(position);

        String value4 = URL_ArrayList.get(position);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),value1+" "+value2+" "+value3+" "+value4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Venky your code works perfectly. I knew someone  here could point me in the right direction and thanks to everyone for their replies

Answer (score 0):

try to change the line

> String text = (String) LISTVIEW.getItemAtPosition(position);

with

> String text = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

this should be the way ListView works.
Also i suggest you to not use Capital Cases with variables, usually in Java is used a [CamelCase](https://sanaulla.info/2008/06/25/camelcase-notation-naming-convention-for-programming-languages/) convention. And also have a look at RecyclerView, that usually is implemented today much more than ListView, because allow a great level of customization

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion but I am still getting null in the toast. Any other ideas?

Comment: use the debug mode put a breakpoint on the line I suggest you and tell me what value is passed in text. and Also which value was passed in the case you mentioned using LISTVIEW, find android,debug, breakpoint on the internet if you do not know how to do it, is really easy and is your best friend at this learning initial stage.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
ShowSQLiteDBdata() in onCreate() instead of onResume() method

Answer (score 0):

Pls use below code within listview setOnItemClickListener :-

```
      String genreID = ID_ArrayList.get(position);

      String genre = GENRE_ArrayList.get(position);

      String genreName = NAME_ArrayList.get(position);

      String genreUrl = URL_ArrayList.get(position);
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), genreID+", "+genre+","+genreName+", "+genreUrl+", "+, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

its return render data of listview.